# How to send message to a specific user from discord bot using discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to send a message from my discord bot to a specific user like myself using my discord id.
I have tried the following code where my client object is named as bot:

`bot.users.get("My Id copied from discord").send("Message to Send");`

but it gives the following error in the terminal:

***bot.users.get is not a function***

Please help me in resolving this error.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 you need to use `cache` to access the `users` collection

```js
bot.users.cache.get('ID').send('hello')
```

You need to use `users.fetch()` instead since the user might not be cached

```js
const user = await bot.users.fetch('ID')
user.send('hello')
```